# UIAlertController changes UIButton colour after dismiss

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton

Whats happening is that I am making a post request using Alamofire.
Now when I hit api the button colour is light grey but after I show some message using AlertController and then Click on Ok Button the colour of button changes to Blue. Now in Identity inspector, button has UIButton set as class. I don't know whats going wrong I am not changing buttons background at any stage for selected, highlighted or other states.
There is no button category as well.

Attached images display step by step process.

pop is showing

[image]

blue background button

[image]

Comment: Where is the code you grey out the button?

Comment: the button's colour is set from storyboard. 
the odd thing is after displaying the popup it changes to tint colour.

Moreover if I don't give corner radius everything works fine but the moment I set corner radius of this button in viewDidLoad then this problem occurs.

Changing the tint colour to buttons original background colour resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the conversation, but for everyone looking for the answer, changing `button.tintAdjustmentMode = .normal` will ignore tint changes.